# Printer "filter failed" attribute on hpm128fw

Tags: printing, hp

I have an M128fw on local network. The problem is I can only print linux text editor files with it. It stops all other jobs with "filter failed" attribute. I tried various configurations while setting the printer up. Am i missing something more basic here?

```
E [18/Jul/2017:19:58:33 +0530] [Job 1] Job stopped due to filter errors; please consult the error_log file for details.
...
D [18/Jul/2017:19:58:33 +0530] [Job 1] Executing backend "/usr/lib/cups/backend/socket"...
D [18/Jul/2017:19:58:33 +0530] [Job 1] prnt/hpcups/Hbpl1.cpp 52: Hbpl1 constructor : m_szLanguage = HBPL1STATE: +hplip.plugin-error
D [18/Jul/2017:19:58:33 +0530] [Job 1] prnt/hpcups/HPCupsFilter.cpp 456: m_Job initialization failed with error = 48
D [18/Jul/2017:19:58:33 +0530] [Job 1] PID 31638 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/hpcups) stopped with status 1.
D [18/Jul/2017:19:58:33 +0530] [Job 1] Hint: Try setting the LogLevel to "debug" to find out more.
```

Comment: If you're using CUPS, look at the log files in `/var/log/cups`. If you're NOT using CUPS, I can't help you.

Comment: Please add the relevant parts from `/var/log/cups/error_log`. It will hold more information on the problem. If it shows "error while loading shared libraries:" you need to install that library. In case you put `/var/spool/cups` on a partition... if cups can't write to that directory you get these messages too. Have you upgraded cups recently?

Comment: @waltinator I put up the cups log file

Comment: Don't post whole log files. Read them yourself first, and post subsets of the log that confuse you. Further, see line ONE you your oisted log: "`E [18/Jul/2017:19:58:33 +0530] [Job 1] Job stopped due to filter errors; please consult the error_log file for details.`".

Comment: @waltinator I can't understand the problem through error_log file

Comment: You picked  filter "HPCupsFilter" during install?! That one is not working... Here is a website on this; http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/linux-hp-printing.html

Comment: make what you did an answer, upvote it and gain some rep :) Glad you got it working!

Comment: so great it is working now; so this printer needs an **HP plugin**; if you use **HP's driver**; and you install that with `hp-setup` ...... whereas here it would seem tambakoo ihas switched and is now using the FOOMATIC drivers; HP comment "This printer REQUIRES a downloadable driver plug-in, which is required to enable print, fax or scan support. Use hp-setup to install the printer, and to download and install the plug-in. " http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/laserjet/hp_laserjet_pro_mfp_m128fw.html

Comment: @Rinzwind when it worked yesterday, the printer was churning out ink smudges and not my document so I assumed it was working but low on ink. I put in new ink today and still it prints smudges and not text.  So it's actually not working yet.